# Beginner... stuck on how to use FormattedFields in java for inserting dates

Tags: java, swing, datetime, jframe, jformattedtextfield

I know the below code is supposed to format the `FormattedTextField` but it doesn't seem to do anything to the form (shown in the picture below). I was wanting, when the form loaded: the text field to look something like this

00/00/2014 - 00:00 am

Where the user is able to

- enter datelike information around the symbol separators (/ or :)
- But where the user could not remove these *symbol separators*

Code:

```
package datefield;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        JFormattedTextField dateField = new JFormattedTextField(new DateFormatter(/*...*/));
    }
```

Screenshot:

I'm not able to show picture as I need 10 reputation, but link to picture is below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO3em.png

Comment: Just a note: manually entered date strings are for the birds, even if you can force format with a `JFormattedTextField`. I suggest using [JDateChooser](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/) instead.

Answer (score 5):

So what's happening in the comments here:

```
JFormattedTextField dateField = new JFormattedTextField(new DateFormatter(/*...*/));?
```

As of now , it's just a comment, so then it is [Using a default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#JFormattedTextField%28%29) , which doesn't do much.

What this means is that you should initialize DateFormatter with arguments, but here we put just comments `/* */` , meaning it uses the default constructor.

But everything I'm telling you is just admittedly some surrounding info. You need to figure this out yourself! Then you'll be proud Java beginner++

[See here to see API page for JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)

Also related: [Java JFormattedTextField for typing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79662/java-jformattedtextfield-for-typing-dates)